# JFileChooser Buttons Customisations

Tags: java, swing, background, gradient, jfilechooser

I am working to giving gradient background to JFileChooser. With StackOverflow help I was able to give the gradient background for the JFileChooser but the buttons in JFilechooser still has the white background. 
Is there any way around to remove it?

```
package javaapplication2;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Paint;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

/**
 *
 * @author navpreet.kaur
 */
class MyFileChooser extends JFileChooser {

    private final Color color1 = Color.DARK_GRAY;
    private final Color color2 = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0.65f); //Color.BLACK;
    final Color color3 = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0.33f);
    private final Color color4 = new Color(0, 0, 0, 0.0f);

    private final int shadowHeight = 20;
    private final GradientPaint mainGradient;
    private final GradientPaint shadowGradient;

    java.net.URL defaultViewURL = IRLookAndFeel.class.getResource("DefaultView_Icon.png");
    java.net.URL detailsViewURL = IRLookAndFeel.class.getResource("DetailsView_Icon.png");
    java.net.URL homeFolderURL = IRLookAndFeel.class.getResource("Home_Icon.png");
    java.net.URL listViewURL = IRLookAndFeel.class.getResource("listView_Icon.png");
    java.net.URL newFolderURL = IRLookAndFeel.class.getResource("Newfolder.png");
    java.net.URL upFolderURL = IRLookAndFeel.class.getResource("Upfolder.png");

    ImageIcon fcDefaultViewIcon = new ImageIcon(defaultViewURL);
    ImageIcon fcDetailsViewIcon = new ImageIcon(detailsViewURL);
    ImageIcon fcHomeFolderIcon = new ImageIcon(homeFolderURL);
    ImageIcon fcListViewIcon = new ImageIcon(listViewURL);
    ImageIcon fcNewFolderIcon = new ImageIcon(newFolderURL);
    ImageIcon fcUpFolderIcon = new ImageIcon(upFolderURL);

    public MyFileChooser() {
        Component[] comps = getComponents();
        recursiveTransparent(comps);

        mainGradient = new GradientPaint(0, 0, color1, 0, 600, color2);
        shadowGradient = new GradientPaint(0, 0, color3, 0, shadowHeight, color4);

           UIManager.put("FileChooser.detailsViewIcon", fcDetailsViewIcon);
           UIManager.put ("FileChooser.homeFolderIcon", fcHomeFolderIcon);
           UIManager.put ("FileChooser.listViewIcon", fcListViewIcon);
           UIManager.put ("FileChooser.newFolderIcon", fcNewFolderIcon);
           UIManager.put ("FileChooser.upFolderIcon", fcUpFolderIcon);
           UIManager.put ("FileChooser.viewMenuIcon", fcDefaultViewIcon);
    }

    private void recursiveTransparent(Component[] comps) {
        for (Component comp : comps) {
            if (comp instanceof JComponent && !(comp instanceof JList)) {
                ((JComponent) comp).setOpaque(false);
            }
            if (comp instanceof Container) {
                Component[] subComps = ((Container) comp).getComponents();
                recursiveTransparent(subComps);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_RENDERING, RenderingHints.VALUE_RENDER_QUALITY);

        int width = getWidth();
        int height = getHeight();


        g2d.setPaint(mainGradient);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

        g2d.setPaint(shadowGradient);
        g2d.fillRect(0, 0, width, shadowHeight);
    }
}`
```

I tried using UIManager properties but nothing helps. My question is about how can i change the icons and the ok and cancel button on JFilechooser ?

![enter image description here][1]

With the code u mentioned I am able to do buttons and the Labels in JFilechooser

```
  if (comp instanceof JButton) {
             JButton b =  (JButton) comp;
             b.setContentAreaFilled(false);
             b.setForeground(Color.white);
             b.setOpaque(false);
             b.setBorderPainted(true);
        }

        if (comp instanceof JLabel) {
             JLabel l =  (JLabel) comp;
             l.setForeground(Color.white);
        }
```

but then there is combo box with the JFilechooser I am trying to change the properties as well but JComboBox is not following the L and F.What can i do?

Comment: Forget about the JFileChooser. First learn how do customize a JButton that is added to a panel. All the file chooser code is irrelevant to the problem of customizing a single button. Simplify the problem when you ask a question. The problem is that the LAF takes control of the painting of JButtons. Until you solve that simpler problem you won't be able to fix the file chooser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LAF controls the background painting of the JButton to give you a simple gradient painting, on Widows. Other LAF may do something different.

If you want to disable this you can try:

```
JButton button = new JButton( "Text Button" );
button.setContentAreaFilled( false );
```

Now the background of the panel will show through.

Comment: Thank you so much Camickr! . I have done buttons and Label customization on the JFileChooser. As far as JCombo Boxes are concerned, I can set there background but the the list in the combo boxes is distorted. How can i paint the combo box within JFileChooser?

Comment: `but the the list in the combo boxes is distorted.` - I have no ideas what that means. Same as my original comment simplify the problem by figuring out how to do it on a combox box added to a panel and forget about the JFileChooser. Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates how you are trying to customize the combo box so we can see what the problems are.